# Ruby on Rails: where returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

In my app I'm obtaining a certain category, and I'm filtering the associated items based on their name.
The following code should be pretty clear:

```
categories = Category.where(:id => params[:category_id]).includes(:items).where("lower(items.name) like ?", "%#{params[:keywords].downcase}%")
```

However, if the name filter excludes all the items, the `categories` object returned by where is nil. Is this the expected behaviour? How can I get the category even either items exist or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way might be to just split the query:

```
@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
@items = @category.items.where("lower(items.name) like ?", "%#{params[:keywords].downcase}%")
```

Based on your code it seems like `category_id` references only 1 category so I've changed it to singular.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply!  Is there a way maintaining my approach (without sppliting)?

Comment: Any reason you're against splitting it?

Comment: In fact, I realized this is the best approach for my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should look into doing an OUTER JOIN against the items table which will give you categories regardless of whether or not their items meet the name filter.