# when where could return nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, where-clause

I just found this question [Ruby on Rails: where returning nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857884/ruby-on-rails-where-returning-nil)

When where could return nil, I could not find the answer in docs.

Comment: i think it should always return a relation object and never nil. do you have an actual case where this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think`where` can return nil. It returns an empty array instead.

from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where  :

> Returns a new **relation**, which is the result of filtering the current relation according to the conditions in the arguments.